# Extjs 4 how hide/show trigger on combox field without doComponentLayout?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am need hide/show trigger on fields (**combobox**,**date** and etc.) without invoke method **doComponentLayout()** (source code of **setReadOnly** method). The method **doComponentLayout()** is very slowly on IE. Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to show/hide the triggerEl that is a property of anything that extends Ext.form.field.Trigger (such as combo, date, etc.).

See live example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/765/

Comment: Property triggerEl is Ext.CompositeElement class, don't work (

Comment: no it's part of Ext.form.field.Trigger, look at the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-property-triggerEl

Comment: m_oLogin, thanks for help! But how i can set trigger is visible, if i set the option hideTrigger: true ?

Comment: Why don't you leave hideTrigger to the default false option, then hide the trigger after the component has been rendered? You can then do a triggerEl.hide() and triggerEl.show() as wished.

Comment: don't forget that triggerEl is a CompositeElement so you need to target the right thing. your example fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/772/

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the **setHideTrigger(true)** method. This is a private method on Ext.form.field.ComboBox - (see [Extjs ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox), make sure to check "Private" in the "Show" menu.)

Calling myCombo.triggerEl.hide() doesn't work if the combo component hasn't been rendered yet.

You can also hide the trigger when component is first initialized by setting the config property **hideTrigger: false.**